# Two similar shell functions that run different programs

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a script that contains two shell functions:

```
runhaskells() {
    local DIR=$PWD
    local TARGET="cabal.sandbox.config"
    while [[ ! -e $DIR/$TARGET -a $DIR != "/" ]]; do
        DIR=$(dirname $DIR)
    done
    if [[ $DIR != "/" ]]; then
        local DB=$(sed -ne '/^package-db: */{s///p;q;}' "$DIR/$TARGET")
        runhaskell -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB" "$@"
    else
        runhaskell "$@"
    fi
} 

ghcs() {
    local DIR=$PWD
    local TARGET="cabal.sandbox.config"
    while [[ ! -e $DIR/$TARGET -a $DIR != "/" ]]; do
        DIR=$(dirname $DIR)
    done
    if [[ $DIR != "/" ]]; then
        local DB=$(sed -ne '/^package-db: */{s///p;q;}' "$DIR/$TARGET")
        ghc -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB" "$@"
    else
        ghc "$@"
    fi
}
```

which obviously is a repeat of each other except for the fact that it calls a different program in each function.  The first function calls the `runhaskell` program while the second function calls the `ghc` program.

How can I DRY this script (either `zsh` or `bash` syntax is fine for me) with the end goal that I should be able to call either function at the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Two simple bash solutions I can think of are:

1. Use a shell script and `$0`/`$BASH_SOURCE` to determine the calling name and a symlink from one name to the other.
2. Two small wrapper functions.

   ```
   h() {
       local DIR=$PWD
       local TARGET="cabal.sandbox.config"
       while [[ ! -e $DIR/$TARGET -a $DIR != "/" ]]; do
           DIR=$(dirname $DIR)
       done
       if [[ $DIR != "/" ]]; then
           local DB=$(sed -ne '/^package-db: */{s///p;q;}' "$DIR/$TARGET")
           set -- "${@:1:1}" -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB" "${@:2}"
           # or this is the order of original arguments and added arguments don't matter
           set -- "$@" -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB"
       fi

       "$@"
   }

   runhaskells() {
       h runhaskell "$@"
   }

   ghcs() {
       h ghc "$@"
   }
   ```

Slightly `DRY`ier version of the above which uses bash's `FUNCNAME` array.

```
    h() {
        local DIR=$PWD
        local TARGET="cabal.sandbox.config"
        while [[ ! -e $DIR/$TARGET -a $DIR != "/" ]]; do
            DIR=$(dirname $DIR)
        done
        if [[ $DIR != "/" ]]; then
            local DB=$(sed -ne '/^package-db: */{s///p;q;}' "$DIR/$TARGET")
            set -- "${@:1:1}" -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB" "${@:2}"
            # or this is the order of original arguments and added arguments don't matter
            set -- "$@" -no-user-package-db -package-db="$DB"
        fi

        "${FUNCNAME[1]%s}" "$@"
    }

    runhaskells() {
        h "$@"
    }

    ghcs() {
        h "$@"
    }
```